How can this code about square matrices be fixed?
I am writing code that involves square matrices and their square-symmetries, but I cannot get to the bottom of it: in particular, I aim to define matrix transformations (that actually compute something) and prove the usual properties about these.
So, I am using Vector from the Standard Library, on top of which I writing functions and theorems that take assumptions along the lines of those required by e.g. Vector.nth_order and Vector.replace_order.  And it all seems nice and workable except that eventually I cannot get to the bottom of satisfying all obligations I encounter in the matrix transforms (see the code below): and I can see why those obligations cannot be satisfied, but I don't know how to rewrite/fix the code/approach in order to achieve my goal.
Is anybody able to shed some light?  --  I would think this is just a beginner's problem.  In fact, I must confess I do not even understand map and fold as defined in Vector and how they can be useful.
[The code is long but I hope it makes the problem clear.  The issue I am trying to solve is at the bottom.]
(* Coq v8.18 *)

From Coq Require Import PeanoNat.
From Coq Require Import Vector.
From Coq Require Import Program.  (* ##### *)

Module SquareSymmetries.

  Import Nat.

  (** The kinds of square-symm transforms. *)
  Variant KSqTx : Set :=  (* (0,0) is top-left *)
    | Iden   (* identity *)
    | Rot1   (* rotation by 90° cw *)
    | Rot2   (* rotation by 180° cw *)
    | Rot3   (* rotation by 270° cw *)
    | RefH   (* reflection about horizontal *)
    | RefV   (* reflection about vertical *)
    | RefD   (* reflection about main diagonal *)
    | RefA.  (* reflection about anti-diagonal *)

  (** Returns the transform inverse kind. *)
  Definition KSqTx_inv K : KSqTx :=
    match K with
    | Iden => Iden
    | Rot1 => Rot3
    | Rot2 => Rot2
    | Rot3 => Rot1
    | RefH => RefH
    | RefV => RefV
    | RefD => RefD
    | RefA => RefA
    end.

  (** The type of coord square-symm transforms. *)
  Definition SqTx_ij : Set :=
    KSqTx -> nat -> nat*nat -> nat*nat.

  (** Returns the transform of the input. *)
  Definition sqTx_ij K n '(i,j) : nat*nat :=
    match K with
    | Iden => (i,j)
    | Rot1 => (j,n-1-i)
    | Rot2 => (n-1-i,n-1-j)
    | Rot3 => (n-1-j,i)
    | RefH => (n-1-i,j)
    | RefV => (i,n-1-j)
    | RefD => (j,i)
    | RefA => (n-1-j,n-1-i)
    end.

  Check sqTx_ij : SqTx_ij.

  (** Returns the transform inverse of the input. *)
  Definition sqTx_inv_ij K n '(i,j) : nat*nat :=
    sqTx_ij (KSqTx_inv K) n (i,j).

  Check sqTx_inv_ij : SqTx_ij.

  (** A useful arithmetic lemma. *)
  Lemma sub_sub_diag : forall n i : nat,
    i <= n -> n - (n - i) = i.
  Proof.
    induction n as [|n' In'].
    all: intros i Ei.
    - inversion Ei.
      reflexivity.
    - destruct i as [|i'].
      + rewrite sub_0_r.
        apply sub_diag.
      + apply succ_le_mono in Ei.
        specialize (In' i' Ei).
        rewrite sub_succ.
        rewrite sub_succ_l.
        * rewrite In'.
          reflexivity.
        * apply le_sub_l.
  Qed.

  (** Transforms produce valid output. *)
  Lemma sqTx_ij_valid : forall K n '(i,j) '(i',j'),
      i < n /\ j < n ->
      (i',j') = sqTx_ij K n (i,j) ->
      i' < n /\ j' < n.
  Proof.
    intros K n [i j] [i' j'] [Hi Hj] Eij'.
    all: destruct K; cbn in Eij'.
    all: inversion Eij'; subst; clear Eij'.
    all: split.
    all: repeat (
      rewrite sub_1_r;
      apply succ_lt_mono;
      rewrite <- sub_succ_l;
      try rewrite succ_pred_pos;
      try rewrite lt_succ_r;
      try apply le_sub_l;
      try apply (lt_lt_0 i n Hi);
      apply lt_le_pred
    ).
    all: assumption.
  Qed.

  (** The transform inverse is
      the inverse of the transform. *)
  Lemma sqTx_inv_ij_correct : forall K n '(i,j),
      i < n /\ j < n ->
      sqTx_inv_ij K n (sqTx_ij K n (i,j)) = (i,j) /\
      sqTx_ij K n (sqTx_inv_ij K n (i,j)) = (i,j).
  Proof.
    intros K n [i j] [Hi Hj].
    split.
    all: destruct K; cbn.
    all: try rewrite ! sub_sub_diag.
    all: try reflexivity.
    all: (
      rewrite sub_1_r;
      apply lt_le_pred
    ).
    all: assumption.
  Qed.

End SquareSymmetries.

Module Matrices.

  (** The type of vectors of length [n]. *)
  Definition Vec (X : Set) n : Set := Vector.t X n.

  (** The type of [ni]*[nj] matrices. *)
  Definition Mat (X : Set) ni nj : Set := Vec (Vec X nj) ni.

  (** Returns the [i]-th element of [v]. *)
  Definition vec_nth {X n} (v : Vec X n)
        {i} (Hi : i < n) : X :=
    nth_order v Hi.

  (** Puts [x] at the [i]-th place of [v]. *)
  Definition vec_set {X n} (v : Vec X n)
        {i} (Hi : i < n) x : Vec X n :=
    replace_order v Hi x.

  (** Returns the [(i,j)]-th element of [s]. *)
  Definition mat_nth {X ni nj} (s : Mat X ni nj)
        {i j} (Hij : i < ni /\ j < nj) : X :=
    let '(conj Hi Hj) := Hij in
    let v := vec_nth s Hi in
    let x := vec_nth v Hj in x.

  (** Puts [x] at the [(i,j)]-th place of [s]. *)
  Definition mat_set {X ni nj} (s : Mat X ni nj)
        {i j} (Hij : i < ni /\ j < nj) x : Mat X ni nj :=
    let '(conj Hi Hj) := Hij in
    let v  := vec_nth s Hi in
    let v' := vec_set v Hj x in
    let s' := vec_set s Hi v' in s'.

  (** The type of [ni]*[nj] matrix transforms. *)
  Definition Tx X ni nj : Set := Mat X ni nj -> Mat X ni nj.

End Matrices.

Module SquareMatrices.

  Import Nat.
  Import Matrices.
  Import SquareSymmetries.
  Import VectorNotations.

  (** The type of square matrices. *)
  Definition SqMat X n : Set := Mat X n n.

  (** The type of square-symm transforms. *)
  Definition SqTx X n : Set := KSqTx -> Tx X n n.

  Check (fun X n => Logic.eq_refl) : forall X n,
    SqTx X n = (KSqTx -> (SqMat X n -> SqMat X n)).

  Program Fixpoint sqTx__aux_ij {X n} K
        (s : SqMat X n) m i j (Em : m = n-j)
        (Hij : i < n /\ j < n) : Vec X m :=
    match m with
    | O    => []
    | S m' =>
        let '(i',j') := sqTx_inv_ij K n (i,j) in
        let Hij' : i' < n /\ j' < n := _ in
        let x := mat_nth s Hij' in
          x :: sqTx__aux_ij K s m' i (S j) _ _
    end.
  Next Obligation.  (* i' < n /\ j' < n *)
    set (H' := sqTx_ij_valid (KSqTx_inv K) n).
    apply (H' (i,j) (i',j')).
    - split; assumption.
    - assumption.
  Defined.
  Next Obligation.  (* m' = n - S j *)
    rewrite sub_succ_r.
    rewrite <- Heq_m.
    reflexivity.
  Defined.
  Next Obligation.  (* i < n /\ S j < n *)
    split.
    - assumption.
    - rewrite <- add_cancel_r with (p:=j) in Heq_m.
      rewrite sub_add in Heq_m.
      + rewrite <- Heq_m.
        rewrite add_succ_comm.
        rewrite add_comm.
        apply lt_add_pos_r.
        give_up.  (* 0 < m' (loop bottom)!! ##### *)
      + apply lt_le_incl.
        assumption.
  Admitted.

  Program Fixpoint sqTx__aux_i {X n} K
        (s : SqMat X n) m i (Em : m = n-i)
        (Hi : i < n) : Mat X m n :=
    match m with
    | O    => []
    | S m' =>
        let Hij := conj Hi _ in
        let v := sqTx__aux_ij K s n i 0 _ Hij in
          v :: sqTx__aux_i K s m' (S i) _ _
    end.
  Next Obligation.  (* 0 < n *)
    apply lt_lt_0 in Hi.
    assumption.
  Defined.
  Next Obligation.  (* n = n - 0 *)
    rewrite sub_0_r.
    reflexivity.
  Defined.
  Next Obligation.  (* m' = n - S i *)
    rewrite sub_succ_r.
    rewrite <- Heq_m.
    reflexivity.
  Defined.
  Next Obligation.  (* S i < n *)
    rewrite <- add_cancel_r with (p:=i) in Heq_m.
    rewrite sub_add in Heq_m.
    - rewrite <- Heq_m.
      rewrite add_succ_comm.
      rewrite add_comm.
      apply lt_add_pos_r.
      give_up.  (* 0 < m' (loop bottom)!! ##### *)
    - apply lt_le_incl.
      assumption.
  Admitted.

  (** Returns the square-transform of the input. *)
  Program Definition sqTx {X n} K
      (s : SqMat X n) : SqMat X n :=
    sqTx__aux_i K s n O _ _.
  Next Obligation.  (* n = n - 0 *)
    rewrite sub_0_r.
    reflexivity.
  Defined.
  Next Obligation.  (* 0 < n *)
    give_up.  (* 0 < n (loop bottom)!! ##### *)
  Admitted.

  Check @sqTx : forall X n, SqTx X n.


  Check [[1;2];[3;4]] : SqMat nat 2.
  Check sqTx Iden [[1;2];[3;4]] : SqMat nat 2.
  Check sqTx Rot1 [[1;2];[3;4]] : SqMat nat 2.
  (* Compute sqTx Iden [[1;2];[3;4]]. *)


  (** ...and so on... *)

End SquareMatrices.


UPDATE:
I have managed to get to the bottom of it as for type-checking, that just needed one more level of matching, but my transform function still won't compute to a value (unless I am not seeing it).
The only thing I have tried is using Qed instead of Defined everywhere, with no better luck: other than that, I cannot guess what the problem is here (I have something similar using sigma-types and that I get to compute to values--it's hidden in a previous edit: why not here?)
Any clue as to how I can get to a useful function?
(This is the last part, the only part that has changed:)

  Program Fixpoint sqTx__aux_ij {X n} K
      (s : SqMat X n) m i j (Em : m = n-j)
      (Hij : i < n /\ j < n) : Vec X m :=
    match m with
    | O    => []
    | S m' =>
        let '(i',j') := sqTx_inv_ij K n (i,j) in
        let Hij' : i' < n /\ j' < n := _ in
        let x := mat_nth s Hij' in
          match m' with
          | O     => [x]
          | S m'' =>
              x :: sqTx__aux_ij K s m' i (S j) _ _
          end
    end.
  Next Obligation.  (* i' < n /\ j' < n *)
    set (H' := sqTx_ij_valid (KSqTx_inv K)).
    apply (H' n (i,j) (i',j')).
    - split; assumption.
    - assumption.
  Defined.
  Next Obligation.  (* S m'' = n - S j *)
    rewrite sub_succ_r.
    rewrite <- Heq_m.
    reflexivity.
  Defined.
  Next Obligation.  (* i < n /\ S j < n *)
    split.
    - assumption.
    - rewrite <- add_cancel_r with (p:=j) in Heq_m.
      rewrite sub_add in Heq_m.
      + rewrite <- Heq_m.
        rewrite add_succ_comm.
        rewrite add_comm.
        apply lt_add_pos_r.
        apply lt_0_succ.
      + apply lt_le_incl.
        assumption.
  Defined.

  Program Fixpoint sqTx__aux_i {X n} K
      (s : SqMat X n) m i (Em : m = n-i)
      (Hi : i < n) : Mat X m n :=
    match m with
    | O    => []
    | S m' =>
        let Hij := conj Hi _ in
        let v := sqTx__aux_ij K s n i 0 _ Hij in
          match m' with
          | O     => [v]
          | S m'' =>
              v :: sqTx__aux_i K s m' (S i) _ _
          end
    end.
  Next Obligation.  (* 0 < n *)
    apply lt_lt_0 in Hi.
    assumption.
  Defined.
  Next Obligation.  (* n = n - 0 *)
    rewrite sub_0_r.
    reflexivity.
  Defined.
  Next Obligation.  (* S m'' = n - S i *)
    rewrite sub_succ_r.
    rewrite <- Heq_m.
    reflexivity.
  Defined.
  Next Obligation.  (* S i < n *)
    rewrite <- add_cancel_r with (p:=i) in Heq_m.
    rewrite sub_add in Heq_m.
    - rewrite <- Heq_m.
      rewrite add_succ_comm.
      rewrite add_comm.
      apply lt_add_pos_r.
      apply lt_0_succ.
    - apply lt_le_incl.
      assumption.
  Defined.

  Program Definition sqTx__aux {X n} K
      (s : SqMat X n) m (Em : m = n) : Mat X m n :=
    match m with
    | O    => []
    | S m' => sqTx__aux_i K s m O _ _
    end.
  Next Obligation.  (* 0 < S m' *)
    apply lt_0_succ.
  Defined.

  (** Returns the square-transform of the input. *)
  Definition sqTx {X n} K s : SqMat X n :=
    sqTx__aux K s n Logic.eq_refl.

  Check @sqTx : forall X n, SqTx X n.


  Check (fun K => sqTx K [[1;2];[3;4]]) :
      forall K, SqMat nat 2.
  Compute sqTx Iden [[1;2];[3;4]].
  Compute
    let s := sqTx Iden [[1;2];[3;4]] in
    let H := lt_0_succ 1 in  (* 0 < (S 1) *)
    let x := mat_nth s (conj H H) in x.



That must have to do with the fact that terms in Prop types do not reduce, still I cannot pin it down: why do Vector.nth_order and Vector.replace_order work and the code above, which is mostly just wrapping around them, won't?  I cannot nail the place in my code where the conditions I am bringing around matter to computing the associated value(s).
